# Mouse hover tooltip, from data on Folium Choropleth Map in Python

Tags: python, pandas, folium, choropleth

I have drawn the map but the tooltip escapes me. I would like on moue hover to show tooltip with Country Name and Citations from the data in `country_count.csv`, not from the `geo_data`.
Here is the map code

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import folium
import branca
# we define our data which will dictate the choropleth colour scheme
country_count = pd.read_csv('citations_countries.csv')
# we add the geographical coordinates data
country_geo = os.path.join('world-countries.json')
# we define the base map - in our case the whole world
# here we also set the initial view, layout type and initial zoom level
m = folium.Map(location=[0, 0], tiles="OpenStreetMap", zoom_start=1)
# now we start building on top of the base
# in our case it will be one choropleth layer
choropleth = folium.Choropleth(
 geo_data=country_geo,
 name='choropleth',
 data=country_count,
 columns=['Country', 'Citations'], # columns to be used from our data
 key_on='feature.properties.name', # matching elements from the `geojson` data
 fill_color='Greens', # main colour scheme
 fill_opacity=1, # main colour scheme opacity
 line_opacity=0.7, # borders opacity
 legend_name="Citations Count",
    nan_fill_color="white", # missing values color
    nan_fill_opacity=1, # missing values opacity
    highlight=True, # `mouse on` highliht feature for each country
    bins=[1, 15, 25, 50, 75, 150, 200, 400, 1200], # legend bins
    tooltip = folium.Tooltip("test", permanent=False)
).add_to(m)

folium.GeoJson(data=country_count, 
    tooltip = folium.GeoJsonTooltip(fields=('Country', 'Citations',),
                                        aliases=('Country','Citations Count')),
               show = True).add_to(m)

# layers filter, in case we add more layers later on
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m) 

# we load the map in the notebook (we can also save it as HTML file)
m
```

This is the tooltip code I tried

```
folium.GeoJson(data=country_count, 
    tooltip = folium.GeoJsonTooltip(fields=('Country', 'Citations',),
                                        aliases=('Country','Population')),
               show = True).add_to(m)
```

And this is the error it returns

```
ValueError: Cannot render objects with any missing geometries:                      Country  Citations
0   United States of America       1163
1                    Germany        858
2             United Kingdom        807
3                      Spain        452
...
```

This is how the dataframe `country_count.csv` looks

```
    Country Citations
36  Saudi Arabia    23
37  Finland 21
38  Sweden  20
39  Bulgaria    18
40  Malaysia    15
41  Slovakia    15
```

I also tried to add `tooltip` code inside the `choropleth = folium.Choropleth(` class section but no results either.
Tricky one for me and any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: try this:`tooltip = folium.GeoJsonTooltip(fields=['Country', 'Citations',], aliases=['Country','Population']` Weren't the parameters in list form? refer this [page](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/GeoJsonPopupAndTooltip.ipynb).

Comment: Hello there and thanks for the link. I tried that from the page, and there are no errors but no tool-tip appears. I think the difference is that in the example they have geodata+data in same `json` file, while I have geodata in 1 file and my data is in another file, they are loaded as data and geodata, all examples I have seen are with 1 file...

Comment: Basically, it is a form of displaying on a map by associating a geojson file with polygon information and a data file prepared by the user with an ID. So, two files are needed to achieve this.

Comment: Yes, I read the page you shared, but the example there works with only one file which contains both geographical coordinates and user prepared data altogether. Where I have two files, hence it does not work for me.

Comment: I may have confused you. The basic form I'm talking about refers to the [example](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/GeoJSON_and_choropleth.ipynb) on the following page. The 'Using choropleth class' example is what I wanted to convey.